# Slicing image with findContours(cv2)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I cant post the image because of the reputation thing so here is the link to the image I downloaded:

https://www.amvplaygrounds.co.uk/pub/media/catalog/product/a/m/amv_f4-pm-017-shapes-circle-square-rectangle-star-triangle-200mm-2-sq-3d.jpg

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\shapes.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, 0)
contours, hier = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    shape = thresh[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    plt.imshow(shape)
```

It only returns one contour instead of 6 as you can see in the picture.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm always suspicious when folks post a JPEG but their code opens a PNG...

Comment: ... and their image has 6 objects in it yet they expect to find only 5

Comment: Try to use cv2.drawContours

Comment: I saved it as a png because for some reason i have trouble reading jpeg files as you can see in my previous post.

Comment: threshold 200 might be a bit high: try lowering that, or starting with 127.
better yet, make another matrix just for debugging, use a while loop to get a copy of the original image and apply threshold playing with the value ([easy enough to add a slider too](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_trackbar/py_trackbar.html)). as Nuzhny suggests, use drawContours too to debug.

Comment: Well, for some reason  when i do a loop to show an image in jupyter in only shows the last image...
Thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 1):

`findContours()` looks for **white** objects on a **black** background, so you need to threshold like this:

```
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

and you need to find the contours like this:

```
im2, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```